# How do I find tweets given to a web page?

Tags: twitter

I have a web page with the little Twitter API code that allows anyone to tweet about a page.  Now, I want to find the tweets that these people have made.  How do I do that?
Here is example:
http://www.squidoo.com/google-glass-glasses

On the left side it shows 3 tweets.  A search on Twitter for that URL only brings back one real tweet to that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://backtweets.com seems to do it better than twitter itself.